What is the "photoplay" encryption algorithm?
L3HARRIS provides a data encryption unit, called KGT-777 for spacecraft downlinks. The datasheet says it uses the "photoplay" encryption algorithm.
I could not find any reference to this.
What is it?


Too long for a comment:
Interesting question, hard to answer, but maybe others will have a go.
It's most likely a classified algorithm used for military and other government purposes. The fact that it seems almost impossible to find a reference to it by naive online searching most likely indicates that it's in active use.
This would imply that it falls under the category of algorithms called "Type 1".

A Type 1 Product refers to an NSA endorsed classified or controlled cryptographic item for classified or sensitive U.S. government information, including cryptographic equipment, assembly or component classified or certified by NSA for encrypting and decrypting classified and sensitive national security information when appropriately keyed.

If you look at the topic NSA Cryptography on Wikipedia here where equipment with similar names such as KG-227 appear.

Isn't that KG-227, and isn't that equipment that uses the indiciated algorithm, like KGT-777 is the data encryption unit (clearly hardware) in the question?
